# Cypher Query For Creating a Relationship between a node and nodes from a list of IDs?

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, cypher

I am passing list of ids from ajax to the server and I to create a relationship between a particular node and each node with an id in the list. I am doing this --->

```
WITH [{passedString}] AS interests FOREACH (r IN range(0,size(interests)
| CREATE (n)-[f:LIKES]->(m) where n.strEmailId = {passedEmailId} 
and id(m) = r % size(interests)).
```

But it returns an error. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can add a bit more information about the error you get, version of Neo4j etc. But for now, the latest version of Neo4j adds UNWIND. I think you can use it for these kind of things. Next to that, please use some kind of functional ID instead of the node ids.  

    WITH [4,1] AS interests
    UNWIND interests as r
    MATCH (n {strEmailId: "fwwe"}), (m {functionalId: r}) CREATE (n)-    [f:LIKES]->(m)

Comment: unfortunately my firm is using neo4j 2.0.0 so unwind is not supported.